# Dataset with name starting with an underscore doesn't show up in Google BigQuery's Console

Tags: google-bigquery

I created a dataset in the BigQuery Console and started loading data using the console as well. I loaded several files from Google Cloud Storage and then I refreshed the BigQuery Console page and under my project it now says "No datasets found in this project".

If I click on the Recent Jobs link it shows that my data loaded into that dataset:table successfully so why doesn't it show my dataset in the console anymore. Without it I can't query the data I just loaded.

Any suggestions?

Comment: any screenshots? maybe you are logged in now with a different user or project?

Answer (score 6):

Any chance that the dataset name starts with an underscore? If so, this is 'by design'. Datasets starting with underscore are hidden by default -- to list them, you need to pass the 'all' flag.

Obviously this can be better in the UI. When you create a new dataset, the UI adds it to the current view, even if it is 'hidden'. Then when you reload, the dataset doesn't show up because it is hidden.

Just thinking about this, maybe the signal for a hidden dataset shouldn't be the name but an actual flag on the dataset object. Hidden datasets are used to hide the datasets used as the results of queries from showing up in your dataset list.